# : not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub:

Tags: apt, dpkg

I can't install any program because of this error:

```
linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic
```

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried everything on these webpages:

- https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/
- https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-pr...d-error-code-1

and anything I found on this forum.

Nothing works. Any ideas?

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-5.0.0-19-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-modules-5.0.0-19-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 22.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 68.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.0.0-19-generic amd64 5.0.0-19.20 [13.7 MB]
Get:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic amd64 5.0.0-19.20 [8,352 kB]
Fetched 22.1 MB in 7s (3,014 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 228114 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.0.0-19-generic_5.0.0-19.20_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic_5.0.0-19.20_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) over (5.0.0-19.20) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (5.0.0-23.24) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (5.0.0-21.22) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (5.0.0-23.24) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-23-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Killed
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (5.0.0-21.22) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-21-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-19-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.0.0-19-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-5.0.0-19-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-19-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic
 linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic
 linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (5.0.0-23.24) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (5.0.0-21.22) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (5.0.0-23.24) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-23-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (5.0.0-19.20) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-19-generic
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 5.0.0-19-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-5.0.0-19-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-19-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (5.0.0-21.22) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-21-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic
 linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic
 linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (5.0.0-23.24) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (5.0.0-21.22) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (5.0.0-23.24) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-23-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (5.0.0-21.22) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.0.0-21-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
: not foundrub-mkconfig: 5: /etc/default/grub: 
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic
 linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic
```

Comment: Error code 1 simply means that the failure was not dpkg's fault, Please edit your question to show us the complete output. All that cryptic stuff you don't understand is dpkg's detail on exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Please add output of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-5.0.0-19-generic`, `sudo apt-get install -f` and `dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the file `/etc/default/grub` settings file has been deleted or somehow removed.

We can try re-creating that file.

Here is a copy from a fresh 19.04 install:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tsN4RhqRkB

If you open a terminal and run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and put in the the contents of the linked file. When you have the content put in, do Ctl-x to exit, and then type 'y' and press Enter to save.

Then retry the apt commands and see if apt finishes successfully.

Comment: After saving it shows:          [ Error writing /etc/grub/default: No such file or directory ]

Comment: @cyryl Oops, I typed the wrong file name in my instructions. Edited my answer with the right file name, can you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did it and I saw another problem. My file /etc/default/grub was in DOS-Format. I changed it and everything works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad we got it working! Normally, if an answer solves your problem, you should click the check box under the arrows and score to the left of the answer to mark the issue as solved. If you want to discuss/comment on an answer, click the orange add comment under it (basically, the creators of the site discourage putting dialog as an answer - the stack exchange sites are trying to curate a canonical set of answers for questions). And (full disclosure), the people who successfully answered your question get points when you do that.